# Add comment to Instagram Picture from browser console (in native JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, browser, console, instagram

Ive been fighting with that for almost half day;
I wanna add comment to Instagram Picture from console.
But I can not submit the form due to an error.

The comment goes to the textbox but cant submit the form;
Code is simple:

```
var CommentForm = document.querySelector("form.X7cDz");
var commentBox = document.querySelector('textarea.Ypffh');
commentBox.value = "Fantastic picture! ";
CommentForm.submit();
```

sample picture:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CD6PY6OJS-d/

As a result I get this:
"
Error

This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.
"

Comment: Have you then tried private mode? It could be a plugin/extension block...

Comment: you are missing csrf token from what I can see. It's gonna be painful unless you figure out all the parameters that need to be posted to their backend... observe the requests once you do it as user